# getURL("javascript:window.close();") not working in current web browser like firefox mozilla and google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, firefox, actionscript-2

I am using as2 flash cs5. I have made many games and added `getURL("javascript:window.close();")` to exit window. it works in enternet explorer but not working now on google chrome and firefox mozilla.

when i press the button it says :

> Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

please help

Comment: That is security setting....you can not close a window you did not open.

Comment: this is a good thing

Comment: But it worked earlier. i need to solve this :(

Comment: Will anybody **help** here?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this in firefox by adding following preferences into about:config area.

`dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows`

setting this to true would allow you to close apps with script.